# Ruby analog Java TimeUnit

Tags: java, ruby, timeunit

So in java we have TimeUnit enum with awesome methods.
Any analog in Ruby language?

I need converters seconds to milliseconds, milliseconds to days and so one

Comment: seconds* sorry for typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has 1 to 1 correspondence with TimeUnit but it can be pretty handy sometimes: https://github.com/kachick/time-unit